# Play Local Video on PhoneGap/Cordova in Windows Apps

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing Windows/Windows Phone 8.1 apps using PhoneGap(HTML, JS, CSS, JQM) and some Native/Windows Runtime Component. I want to play a video in a html page. My video file is located inside my Application Folder.
I don't know what's wrong. Please help me.

In the HTML,
I have added:

```
<div id="content">
        <button onclick="domainObject.playVideo()" type="button" data-theme="b">Play Video</button>
        <video id="video" src='' type='video/mp4' width="400" autoplay="autoplay" controls></video>
</div>
```

And in the JS:

```
var domainObject = { 
    playVideo: function () {
        var vidPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + "\\test.mp4";
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', vidPath);

        video.appendChild(source);
        video.load();
        video.play();  
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you are seeing in a bit more detail? Is the video file simply not playing when you load your HTML?  Any errors? Can you load your video when you enter its URL directly? Thanks!

Comment: Yes my video file is not loading/playing, my app simply suspends or force closes without showing any errors. I think it is showing this issue due to video file path.